# Deploying Client/Server Java Application

Tags: java, client, server, desktop

Good Day,

I have been asked to create a Java client/server desktop application for a deployment on a Windows server. My problem is i have done this many times but never for deployment for a real client. So my questions are what tools technologies, architecture designs procedures should i consider for this project. From conceptualization to actual deployment, what things should i consider, btw, the software will be using Microsoft access as the database... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a standalone application is out-dated but still you can make it.
SWING make gives you a elegant look for desktop client.

Architecture designs can be decided based on the requirement of the software.

Note: This is may fit your requirements but I believe that it doesn't fit for your broader question.

Comment: ye im aware of those things, any advice for deployment to server? and building the app, especially since i wont have continuous access to the server? do you suggest i build a web app that communicates with the web app?

Comment: That's right go for the web app. So that even if the requirements changes to the web-based one then you can stick to that easily.

Comment: what tools do you suggest for that

Comment: Ok go for the eclipse (freeware) or intellij (Paidversion). And in-terms of server go for Apache tomcat.